# How to receive and post with the same connection in curl?

Tags: c++, bash, curl, request

What I need to do is download a page, find a number in the page and multiply it by 4; then send that new number back to the page using POST but with the same connection.

I was doing this completely fine with curl and C++ but two connections. Is there a way to do this with only one connection in curl?

I tried reading the `curl --help` but I didn't know what to look for and didn't see how to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use the same connection? If you do, you'll need to use libcurl rather than using a command line call.

Comment: And keep in mind that you can split one cookie session across multiple curl commands.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes I'm using `-b cookies.txt`

Comment: @Daniel I am sure that it needs to be the same connection. And what do you mean by libcurl? Is that in C++? Also, is this easier to do in php?

Comment: libcurl is a C library for doing the things you do with curl, but that would give you access to tell curl to go ahead and reuse the connection.  PHP works also, and I believe it comes with curl install by default.   I've also done stuff like this in Java using Apache-Commons http.

Comment: Hm.. I wish there was a way to just do this in bash. Maybe php will be easier